# Fixed a bug of views django: Page not found

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

My english is not good !
I have tried many ways but still get error: page not found.
File views.py:

```
def create_article(request, template_name='vlogntruong/create_article.html'):
if request.method == "POST":
    create_form = VlogForm(request.POST)
    if create_form.is_valid():
        new_article = create_form.save()
        return HttpResponeRedirect(new_article.get_absolute_url())
else:
    create_form = VlogForm(request)

template_context = {
    'create_form': create_form,
}

return render_to_response(
    template_name,
    template_context,
    RequestContext(request)
)
```

File forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import VlogNTruong

class VlogForm(forms.Form):
    title= forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':50}))
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50,
                           widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':50}))
    sumary = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":10, "cols":80}))
    content = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":20, "cols":80}))
    video = forms.CharField(required = False,
                              widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':60}))

    def save(self):
        create_form = VlogNTruong(title = self.cleaned_data['title'],
                           name = self.cleaned_data['name'],
                           sumary = self.cleaned_data['content'],
                           content = self.cleaned_data['content'],
                           video = self.cleaned_data['video'])
        create_form.save()
        return create_form
```

File models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib import admin
import datetime



class VlogNTruong (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug_field = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sumary = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    video = EmbedVideoField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-time_create',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('vlogntruong.views.article_detail', [self.slug_field])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug_field:
            self.slug_field = slugify(self.title)
        super(VlogNTruong, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

file html

```
{% extends 'vlogntruong/base.html' %}
{% block panel_content %}
<form action="/" method="post">{% csrf_token %} 
<table>
    {{form.as_table}}
</table>
<input type="submit" name="Create" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

file urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('vlogntruong.views',
    url(r'^$', 'list_article',
        {'template_name':'vlogntruong/list_article.html'}),
    url(r'^(?P<slug_field>[-\w\d]+)/$', 'article_detail'),
    url(r'^create/$', 'create_article'),
)
```

Help me

Error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    /nhuttruong/create/
No VlogNTruong matches the given query.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file.   Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? Which part?

Comment: Error message: Page not found. No other error

Comment: You don't have any method in your views that matches the methods in your urls.py, which is why django cannot find anything. You have `list_article`, `article_detail`, and `create`, but in your views.py you have `create_article` which is not even mapped.

Comment: I still have the bug!

Comment: Please update the question and add the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your `save()` method in your form is not returning the object it creates in the database, it is returning the *unsaved* instance, for which you are trying to get the redirect url.

I would suggest you read the [modelforms guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/) to help you along.

Your form should look like this:

```
from django import forms
from .models import VlogNTruong

class VlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title= forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':50}))
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50,
                           widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':50}))
    sumary = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":10, "cols":80}))
    content = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":20, "cols":80}))
    video = forms.CharField(required = False,
                              widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':60}))

    class Meta:
        model = VlogNTruong
```

Then, in your views, you need to adjust it like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def create_article(request, template_name='vlogntruong/create_article.html'):
    create_form = VlogForm(request.POST or None)
    if create_form.is_valid():
        new_article = create_form.save()
        return HttpResponeRedirect(new_article.get_absolute_url())
    template_context = {'create_form': create_form,}
    return render(request, template_name, template_context)
```

You also need to make sure that the `VlogNTruong` model has a [`get_absolute_url` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) which returns a URL. Your method just returns a tuple, fix it like this:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    return reverse('vlogntruong.views.article_detail', args=[self.slug_field])
```

Finally your `__unicode__` method must return a unicode object, yours is returning a string:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode('{}'.format(self.title))
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression that you are using in the third url() does not match with the requested URL:

**r'^create/$'** will not match **'/nhuttruong/create/'**

To achieve your objective you should use something like **r'.+/create/$'**

Comment: urls.py of folder app, urls.py main: url(r'^nhuttruong/', include('vlogntruong.urls')),